# Pros/Cons of Parse Dashboard local installation vs deployment

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, deployment, dashboard

I wasn't able to find solid information on this and I wanted to ask developers who use Parse Dashboard:

What are the pros/cons of Parse Dashboard local installation vs deployment?

I currently run the Parse Dashboard on local installation, but I know that deployment to Heroku is also an option (my app is deployed on Heroku). I wanted to gather some information before deploying/not deploying.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also have it running locally and I think for security reasons it's best to do so. If you setup the dashboard on the same server on which Parse is running, then you will have to take security measure to protect access to the dashboard and the config file which includes your masterkey and all that. This definitely outweighs the arguments to host it locally, which in my opinion only is that it's easier to access the dashboard.

If you really want to setup a dashboard on a server at least do it on a separate server.